# Display INR number only if it's a number with more than 3 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JSFiddle DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/bukh7jwL/**

I have a table with text & numbers and facing 2 problems.

1. It disables all the text values and displays it as ₹NaN!!
2. I would like to avoid applying the JS if the number has less than 100 as value or 3 digits.

How do I go about doing this?

HTML:

```
<center>
    <p>
      <table>
        <tr><td>This is amazing</td></tr>
        <tr><td>92834</td></tr>
        <tr><td>33</td></tr>
        <tr><td>What?</td></tr>
      </table>
</center>
```

JS:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  var monetary_value = $(this).text();
  var i = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
  }).format(monetary_value);
  $(this).text(i);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `It disables all the text values`? You are trying to convert text to currency. So it will show up as NaN.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/v83n25gm/1/?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes!! Please post as an answer.

Comment: upvoted, to neutralize the negative vote.  This is always my policy.  No question is stupid enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following statement to your code to check if we want to run the `NumberFormat`.

`$.isNumeric(monetary_value) && (monetary_value < 100 || monetary_value.length == 3)`

`$.isNumeric(monetary_value)` checks if it's a number.

`(monetary_value < 100 || monetary_value.length == 3)` checks if the value is below 100 or the length is 3 characters long.

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  var monetary_value = $(this).text();
  if ($.isNumeric(monetary_value) && (monetary_value < 100 || monetary_value.length == 3)) {
    var i = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'INR'
    }).format(monetary_value);
  }
  $(this).text(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
    <p>
      <table>
        <tr><td>This is amazing</td></tr>
        <tr><td>92834</td></tr>
        <tr><td>33</td></tr>
        <tr><td>What?</td></tr>
      </table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check if the string is a number or not after that you need to check if the number digits are 3 or more. After that using `toLocaleString()` the number will be converted into INR currency

```js
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

$('td').each(function() {
  var monetary_value = $(this).text();
  if(isNumeric(monetary_value)) {
    let moneyVal = parseFloat(monetary_value);
    if( (moneyVal < 100 || moneyVal.toString().length == 3) ){
    var i = moneyVal.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
});
    $(this).text(i);
    
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<center>
    <p>
      <table>
        <tr><td>This is amazing</td></tr>
        <tr><td>92834</td></tr>
        <tr><td>33</td></tr>
        <tr><td>What?</td></tr>
      </table>
</center>
```